# java8 Stream API filter Map based on arrayList

Tags: java

```
Class Person {
     Map<String, String> personNature = new HashMap<String,String>();
     // Getter and Setter of Map

     public void setBehaviour(String key, String value) {
        personNature.put(key, value);
     }
}

main(String[] abc) { 

    Person p = new Person();
    Map<String, String> personAllNature = new HashMap<String, String>();
    allNatures.put("personName", "Raj");
    allNatures.put("personAggresive", "8");
    allNatures.put("personShyness", "5");
    allNatures.put("personCourage", "9");
    allNature.put("personFakness", "2");


    List<String> personVisibleAttributes= new ArrayList<String>();
    personVisibleAttributes.add("personAggresive");
    personVisibleAttributes.add("personShyness");

}
```

Now i want to filter Map (personAllNature ) in such a way that when i want to set Person's Map i will get only those values from Map which is in List(personVisibleAttributes)

something like below :

```
personAllNature.entrySet().parallelStream()
        .filter(map -> personVisibleAttributes.contains(map.getKey()))
        .forEach(entry -> p.setBehaviour( entry.getKey(), entrygetValue())
```

Overall :

filter a Map based on values in List where 
Map key is in List 
and then set all those map value in Person instance.

Comment: Didn't you just answer your own question? Which bit are you stuck on?

Comment: Is `personAllNature`, `allNatures`, and `allNature` supposed to be the same variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you'll only add the `attributes` that are in the `List` you can directly iterate from it :

```
personVisibleAttributes.forEach(k -> p.setBehaviour(k, personAllNature.get(k));
```

Comment: This is what i am looking for